# A question about non-invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to prove the following statements?

"if $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is a non-invertible"
$\Rightarrow$
"There exist a system of linear equations $Ax=b$ which is IMPOSSIBLE"

($x$ and $b$ is an $\mathbb{R}^n$ vectors)

So, this is about the "Existence of impossible system of linear equations".
I have been trying to prove this but it's not easy for me..

The "Existence of indeterminate $Ax=b$" was simply solved with the aid of fundamental theorem of invertible matrices and the case in which b is a zero vector. But "Existence of impossible $Ax=b$ for all non-invertible matrix $A$" is not easy for me.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: An $\;n\times n\;$ matrix can be seen as a map from an $\;n\,-$ dimensional space to itself (in this case, apparently, it is $\;\Bbb R^n\;$) , so the matrix $\;A\;$ is non-invertible iff it is not an isomorphism iff it is not injective iff it is not surjective. Thus, there exist  $\;b\in\Bbb R^n\;$ s.t. $\;b\notin Im(A)\iff Ax=b\;$ isn't solvable.

Comment: Consider the zero matrix and how $x$ and $b$ must be related. Now show that a single row of zeros is sufficient to make the same problem happen. Then generalize to matrices that are not row-reduced.

Comment: (to DonAntonio) Thank you! Actually I came up with the proof just after I wrote this question. My proof was using『'A is non-invertible' ↔ 'the set of row-vectors of A is linear dependent'』. Yours is way more concise and clear. Thank you again!

Comment: (to CyclotomicField) Thank you. I think I really have to invest more effort to linear algebra to escape from my immaturity.

Comment: “Impossible” should be “inconsistent” — having no solution.